# Recommended location to store intelliJ project files for project where the set of repos/modules it contains will change over time

Tags: intellij-idea

If I have an intelliJ project containing a number of git repos, the set of which will change over time, where/how should I store the project configuration files (`/.idea` folder) itself?

(For avoidance of doubt, what I mean above is that after some time, I will want to remove a repo/module from the project and add another of a different name.)

I have a project like this and have run into problems as I wanted to rename one of the repos, but the fact that the intelliJ project files (`./idea` folder) is contained within the repo/directory I want to rename, seems to be creating issues (specifically, when I change 'module name' in project settings, quit and reload, the change is not saved, and the old directory/module name reappears, which I don't want).

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty project in any appropriate location:

[image]

It will create an `.idea` project configuration directory in the specified path. And then add other projects there as [new modules from existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#import-module).

Comment: Thanks. If I have an existing project, is it sound to simply move/copy the .idea folder from it to make a new 'empty project', and thus retain some existing settings?

Comment: Would that be what "New Project from Existing Sources" is for?  It seems you've thought of everything :)

Comment: Another trick I used is to duplicate the existing directory where I had the .idea folder co-located inside a code module, delete ./idea, then add back that code module (via its .iml file) as a new module from existing source to the new project. This seems to work, but still checking.